# I don't know how to reset all the function in the 2nd frame after i hit the okay button on the JOptionPane. What to do?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane, jprogressbar

I am using JCreator as my IDE and this program has two frames 1st is the startup frame you will just press start and my problem is on the 2nd frame which is I want to reset the all the function in that frame as I click OK on the `JOptionPane` or what would you suggest on doing. It is on line 135.

```
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class OddEven extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new OddEven();
    }
        JButton b1;
        JProgressBar p;
        int i = 0;
        
        public OddEven() 
        {
            Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xFFFFFF),5);
            
            JLabel l = new JLabel("ODD or EVEN");     
            l.setForeground(new Color(0x143D59));
            l.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,25));
            l.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
            l.setOpaque(true);  
            l.setBorder(border);
            l.setVerticalAlignment(l.CENTER);
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(l.CENTER);     
            l.setBounds(100,65,300,50);   
                
            JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
            buttonpanel.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
            buttonpanel.setBounds(100,125,300,60);
            buttonpanel.setLayout(null);
                        
            b1 = new JButton ("Start Game");
            
            b1.setBounds(100,10,100,25);
            b1.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
            b1.setFocusable(false);
            b1.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,15));
            b1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            
            p = new JProgressBar(0, 200);
            p.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
            p.setForeground(new Color(0xF49F1C));
            p.setBounds(50,40,200,20);
            p.setStringPainted(true);
            
            Timer t = new Timer(1, this);
            
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    t.start();
                }
            });

            add(l);  
            add(buttonpanel);   
            buttonpanel.add(p);
            buttonpanel.add(b1);
                                                                                               
            setTitle("RON BALID");
            setLayout(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(500,300);  
            setResizable(false);                              
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     
            setVisible(true);
            getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
        }
        int score = 0;
        int count = 0; 
        int lifecounter = 3;
        
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNum;
            
        JFrame f;
        JPanel rNumpanel, aPanel, scorePanel;
        JButton l1,l2,time;
        JLabel rScore,nScore,rNum2;
        JProgressBar timeBar;
        int num;
        int timerCounter;
        Timer t1;   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {   
            if(i==200)
            {
            //-------------------JLABEL--------------------------   
                
                Border border3 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xFFFFFF),5);
                rNum2 = new JLabel();
                randomNum = r.nextInt(100);
                rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                rNum2.setBounds(190,25,100,50);
                rNum2.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,50));
                rNum2.setForeground(Color.red);
                rNum2.setBorder(border3);
                rNum2.setVerticalAlignment(rNum2.CENTER);
                rNum2.setHorizontalAlignment(rNum2.CENTER);
                
                rScore = new JLabel("");
                rScore.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                rScore.setBounds(380,10,50,50);
                rScore.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,20));
                
                nScore = new JLabel("SCORE:"); 
                nScore.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                nScore.setBounds(300,-15,100,100);
                nScore.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,20));
    
                
            //-------------------JLABEL--------------------------
                
            //-----------------CONDITION-------------------------           
            
                timeBar = new JProgressBar(0, 200);
                timeBar.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                timeBar.setForeground(new Color(0xF49F1C));
                timeBar.setBounds(140,0,200,20);
                timeBar.setStringPainted(true);
                timeBar.setString("TIMER"); 
                
                time = new JButton ("10s");
                time.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));
                time.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                time.setBounds(55,15,50,20);
                time.setFocusable(false);
                time.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,12));
                    t1 = new Timer(25, timerEvent ->
                        {
                            if (timerCounter == 200 ) 
                            {       
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your score is: "+ score +" / "+ count);
                                count = 0;
                                score = 0;              
                                rScore.setText("");
                                randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                                rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));   
                                                        
                            }
                            timerCounter += 1;
                            timeBar.setValue(timerCounter);
                        });
                time.addActionListener(timeEvent ->
                    {
                    t1.start();                                         
                    }
                    );
                    
                l1 = new JButton("ODD");
                l1.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                l1.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
                l1.setBounds(55,13,100,50);
                l1.setFocusable(false);
                l1.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,20));
                l1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()); 
                l1.addActionListener(event -> {
            count = count+1;
            num = Integer.parseInt(rNum2.getText());
            
            if (timerCounter == 200)
            {
                if (num%2!=0)
                {       
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);    
                }
                else
                {
                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (num%2!=0)
                {
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));                       
                }
                else
                {   

                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                }
            }
        });         
                l2 = new JButton("EVEN");
                l2.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                l2.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
                l2.setBounds(315,13,100,50);
                l2.setFocusable(false);
                l2.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,20));
                l2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
                l2.addActionListener(act -> {
            count = count+1;
            num = Integer.parseInt(rNum2.getText());
            if (timerCounter == 200)
            {
                if (num%2==0)
                {
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                }
                else
                {                       

                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);    
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));               
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (num%2==0)
                {                   
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                    
                }
                else
                {                                                                               
                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                }
            }
            });
            
            //-----------------CONDITION-------------------------
            
            //-----------------PANELS----------------------------           
                aPanel = new JPanel ();
                aPanel.setLayout(null);
                aPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                aPanel.setBounds(10,110,475,75);
                
                rNumpanel = new JPanel();
                rNumpanel.setLayout(null);
                rNumpanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                rNumpanel.setBounds(10,20,475,75);
                
                scorePanel = new JPanel ();
                scorePanel.setLayout(null);
                scorePanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                scorePanel.setBounds(10,180,475,75);
            //-----------------PANELS----------------------------   
            //------------------FRAME----------------------------           
                f = new JFrame("ODD or EVEN Game");
                f.setLayout(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(500,300);  
                f.setResizable(false);                              
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                
                        
                f.add(aPanel);
                f.add(rNumpanel);
                f.add(scorePanel);
                aPanel.add(l1);
                aPanel.add(l2); 
                
                
        
                rNumpanel.add(rNum2);   
                scorePanel.add(rScore);
                scorePanel.add(nScore);
                scorePanel.add(time);
                rNumpanel.add(timeBar);
                
         //------------------FRAME----------------------------  
                                        
                dispose();
            }
            i++;
            p.setValue(i);      
        }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class OddEven extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new OddEven();
    }
        JButton b1;
        JProgressBar p;
        int i = 0;
        
        public OddEven() 
        {
            Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xFFFFFF),5);
            
            JLabel l = new JLabel("ODD or EVEN");     
            l.setForeground(new Color(0x143D59));
            l.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,25));
            l.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
            l.setOpaque(true);  
            l.setBorder(border);
            l.setVerticalAlignment(l.CENTER);
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(l.CENTER);     
            l.setBounds(100,65,300,50);   
                
            JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
            buttonpanel.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
            buttonpanel.setBounds(100,125,300,60);
            buttonpanel.setLayout(null);
                        
            b1 = new JButton ("Start Game");
            
            b1.setBounds(100,10,100,25);
            b1.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
            b1.setFocusable(false);
            b1.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,15));
            b1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            
            p = new JProgressBar(0, 200);
            p.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
            p.setForeground(new Color(0xF49F1C));
            p.setBounds(50,40,200,20);
            p.setStringPainted(true);
            
            Timer t = new Timer(1, this);
            
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    t.start();
                }
            });

            add(l);  
            add(buttonpanel);   
            buttonpanel.add(p);
            buttonpanel.add(b1);
                                                                                               
            setTitle("RON BALID");
            setLayout(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(500,300);  
            setResizable(false);                              
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     
            setVisible(true);
            getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
        }
        int score = 0;
        int count = 0; 
        int lifecounter = 3;
        
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNum;
            
        JFrame f;
        JPanel rNumpanel, aPanel, scorePanel;
        JButton l1,l2,time;
        JLabel rScore,nScore,rNum2;
        JProgressBar timeBar;
        int num;
        int timerCounter;
        Timer t1;   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {   
            if(i==200)
            {
            //-------------------JLABEL--------------------------   
                
                Border border3 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xFFFFFF),5);
                rNum2 = new JLabel();
                randomNum = r.nextInt(100);
                rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                rNum2.setBounds(190,25,100,50);
                rNum2.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,50));
                rNum2.setForeground(Color.red);
                rNum2.setBorder(border3);
                rNum2.setVerticalAlignment(rNum2.CENTER);
                rNum2.setHorizontalAlignment(rNum2.CENTER);
                
                rScore = new JLabel("");
                rScore.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                rScore.setBounds(380,10,50,50);
                rScore.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,20));
                
                nScore = new JLabel("SCORE:"); 
                nScore.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                nScore.setBounds(300,-15,100,100);
                nScore.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD,20));
    
                
            //-------------------JLABEL--------------------------
                
            //-----------------CONDITION-------------------------           
            
                timeBar = new JProgressBar(0, 200);
                timeBar.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                timeBar.setForeground(new Color(0xF49F1C));
                timeBar.setBounds(140,0,200,20);
                timeBar.setStringPainted(true);
                timeBar.setString("TIMER"); 
                
                time = new JButton ("10s");
                time.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));
                time.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                time.setBounds(55,15,50,20);
                time.setFocusable(false);
                time.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,12));
                    t1 = new Timer(25, timerEvent ->
                        {
                            if (timerCounter == 200 ) 
                            {
                                
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your score is: "+ score +" / "+ count);
                                count = 0;
                                score = 0;              
                                rScore.setText("");
                                randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                                rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));   
                                                        
                            }
                            timerCounter += 1;
                            timeBar.setValue(timerCounter);
                        });
                time.addActionListener(timeEvent ->
                    {
                    t1.start();                                         
                    }
                    );
                    
                l1 = new JButton("ODD");
                l1.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                l1.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
                l1.setBounds(55,13,100,50);
                l1.setFocusable(false);
                l1.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,20));
                l1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()); 
                l1.addActionListener(event -> {
            count = count+1;
            num = Integer.parseInt(rNum2.getText());
            
            if (timerCounter == 200)
            {
                if (num%2!=0)
                {       
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);    
                }
                else
                {
                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (num%2!=0)
                {
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));                       
                }
                else
                {   

                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                }
            }
        });         
                l2 = new JButton("EVEN");
                l2.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
                l2.setBackground(new Color(0xF4B41A));
                l2.setBounds(315,13,100,50);
                l2.setFocusable(false);
                l2.setFont(new Font("Garamond",Font.BOLD,20));
                l2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
                l2.addActionListener(act -> {
            count = count+1;
            num = Integer.parseInt(rNum2.getText());
            if (timerCounter == 200)
            {
                if (num%2==0)
                {
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                }
                else
                {                       

                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);    
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));               
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (num%2==0)
                {                   
                    score = score+1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                    
                }
                else
                {                                                                               
                    score -=1;
                    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
                    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
                }
            }
            });
            
            //-----------------CONDITION-------------------------
            
            //-----------------PANELS----------------------------           
                aPanel = new JPanel ();
                aPanel.setLayout(null);
                aPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                aPanel.setBounds(10,110,475,75);
                
                rNumpanel = new JPanel();
                rNumpanel.setLayout(null);
                rNumpanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                rNumpanel.setBounds(10,20,475,75);
                
                scorePanel = new JPanel ();
                scorePanel.setLayout(null);
                scorePanel.setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                scorePanel.setBounds(10,180,475,75);
            //-----------------PANELS----------------------------   
            //------------------FRAME----------------------------           
                f = new JFrame("ODD or EVEN Game");
                f.setLayout(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(500,300);  
                f.setResizable(false);                              
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x143D59));
                
                        
                f.add(aPanel);
                f.add(rNumpanel);
                f.add(scorePanel);
                aPanel.add(l1);
                aPanel.add(l2); 
                
                
        
                rNumpanel.add(rNum2);   
                scorePanel.add(rScore);
                scorePanel.add(nScore);
                scorePanel.add(time);
                rNumpanel.add(timeBar);
                
         //------------------FRAME----------------------------  
                                        
                dispose();
            }
            i++;
            p.setValue(i);      
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: My only problem is that i dont know what code to put to reset that frame. Cause its a game.

Comment: I'm sorry because it's just my first time asking here so I dont know how to ask or anything but I did Completed the code and it works well now what i did is i resetted the counter of my timer and ten stop it. 
` if (timerCounter == 200 ){         {  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your score is: "+ score +" / "+ count);
count = 0;
score = 0;    
rScore.setText("");
randomNum = r.nextInt(1000);
rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum));
timerCounter = 0;
t1.stop();} `
its on line 135 in the end i dont need to reset my JFrame just the timer

Answer (score 1):

I completed the code and it works well now, what I did was reset the counter of my timer and then stop it.

```
if (timerCounter == 200 ){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your score is: "+ score +" / "+ count); 
    count = 0; 
    score = 0; 
    rScore.setText(""); 
    randomNum = r.nextInt(1000); 
    rNum2.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum)); 
    timerCounter = 0; 
    t1.stop();
}
```

It's on line 135 in the end. I don't need to reset the `JFrame`, just the timer.